# can i run ubuntu on my hp Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz old laptop?

Tags: 20.04

i want to shift to ubuntu but i am confused that which version will suitable for my laptop!
my laptop is very old with cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
name: hp pavillion 4th genaration laptop

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you’re in doubt, use the “Try Ubuntu” feature of the installation USB and see how things perform. If the system works decently, then it’ll seem even faster when the OS is installed (because the local disk is faster than USB) 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I use devices as old as from 2005 in QA for Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu.  For older devices, the *lighter flavors* tend to perform better, but I'm using a 2008 dell right now (c2q-9400) which is a number of generations older than your box, but I'd evaluate what I run using other details than what you provided anyway (ie. CPU isn't the most important variable in my opinion)

Comment: thanks for your opinion?